# Haiku tag switches to Poetry?

Tags: discussion, tags

Scrolling through the tags, I realized there was a Haiku tag, so I tried to remove the Poem tag and add Haiku. However, when I saved it, it changed to the Poetry tag. Why is this? If this happens to everyone, then should the tag be deleted?

Should the questions under the Haiku tag all just be moved under the Poetry one, as it covers "Puzzles that are presented in the form of any of the various types of poetry"?

Answer (score 2):

Haiku is a tag synonym for poetry, as it says [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/poetry/synonyms)

> ### Tag synonyms for [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry)
>
> Incorrectly tagged questions are hard to find and answer. If you know of **common, alternate spellings or phrasings** for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.
>
> The following tags will be remapped to [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry)
>
> [haiku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiku)

Comment: Should limericks be included in that then?